# Xamarin - is there a cross-platform equivalent of JobScheduler

Tags: xamarin

I am writing an app that needs to keep a local database in sync with a remote one, using web requests.

I would like the app to be available on all phone platforms - Android, iOS and Windows Phone.

It looks to me as if `JobScheduler` is probably the most efficient way to implement this in Android - you can get it to call your code only when the network is available.

Is there any equivalent in iOS? What about Windows Phone?